# Cannot use brew install watchman

Tags: react-native, homebrew, watchman

I am getting this error when trying to install **watchman**.

```
Warning: No available formula with the name "watchman".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae and casks...
Error: No formulae or casks found for watchman.
```

I'm following the `react-native` docs and one of the first steps is to `brew install watchman`. But I am getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

fixed by removing `remote.origin.url`.

```
git config --global --unset remote.origin.url
```